# SQL Server find and update values with different case latter when they are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to match same values but with different case letters for example.

```
value1=TesT
value2=test
```

I have 2 columns that i want to synchronize i made a procedure that sync fine but doesnt not sync values that are with different case letter and same value.
 I don't what to insert all the values from column1 to column2 every time that i want to run the procedure that will take much time.

here is my query

```
DECLARE nam CURSOR FOR
select ipaname, ipaadr, vidname, vidadr, ipadogno as dogno from tmpNames
        DECLARE @dogno varchar(5)
        DECLARE @ipaname VARCHAR(200)
        DECLARE @ipaadr VARCHAR(200)
        DECLARE @vidname VARCHAR(200)
        DECLARE @vidadr VARCHAR(200)
open nam
    fetch next from nam into @ipaname, @ipaadr, @vidname, @vidadr, @dogno
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        DECLARE @sync varchar(200)
if @ipaname!=@vidname or @ipaadr!=@vidadr begin
            set @sync = 'update client set name=''' +cast(@vidname as VARCHAR(max))+ ''', adr=''' +cast (@vidadr as varchar(max))+ ''' where dogno=''' + @dogno + '''' 
            Execute(@sync) at ipacct5
            end
    fetch next from nam into @ipaname, @ipaadr, @vidname, @vidadr, @dogno
END
close nam
deallocate nam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql Server default collation is `Case insensitive` (I think that is what your problem). If you need to do a case sensitive search, use `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` collation.

You can check your current server collation as:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('Collation')
```

If it says `"...CI.."`, that means Case Insensitive, otherwise it should be `"...CS.."`.

Following is an example on how to use collation on comparison(**[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2228e/6)**):

```
declare @s1 nvarchar(10) = 'Test',
        @s2 nvarchar(10) = 'test'

--Here Test = test
if (@s1 = @s2)  SELECT 'CASE INSENSITIVE';

declare @s1 nvarchar(10) = 'Test',
        @s2 nvarchar(10) = 'test'

--In this case, Test <> test
if (@s1 != @s2 Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS) SELECT 'CASE SENSITIVE';
```

Also, I think you may not need a cursor, replace it with following update query.

```
--Check the SELECT query first and if okay comment SELECT and uncomment UPDATE
select c.name, t.vidname , c.adr, t.vidadr 
--update c set c.name=t.vidname , c.adr=t.vidadr 
from client c 
      join tmpNames t on c.dogno= t.ipadogno
where (t.ipaname != t.vidname Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
      or (t.ipaadr != t.vidadr Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
```

Comment: Ok the select work fine but when i try to execute 0 rows affected.

Comment: thanks man i fix it i needed to add colliton in the select. Works Perfect.